# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'firebase' when trying to use serverTimestamp in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I try to add serverTimestamp() i get the error that firestore (web V9) is not imported. is there any way to use serverTimestamp or just import firestore/firebase so that I can use it?

```
addDoc(collection(db, 'rooms', roomId, 'messages'), {
  message:input,
  name:user.displayName,
  timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()// the issue 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change in serverTimestamp, all you need is to import firebase&firestore correctly (version 9 compat)

```
import firestore from 'firebase/compat';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `admin.firestore.FieldValue` namespace to use `serverTimestamp()` in the new Modular SDK. You can simply import it as shown below:

```
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore"
// import serverTimestamp ----->^

addDoc(collection(db, 'rooms', roomId, 'messages'), {
  message: input,
  name: user.displayName,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp() // <-- usage 
})
```

Importing `compat` version of Firestore just for `serverTimestamp()` while you are actually using Modular SDK kind of defeats purpose of having Modular SDK.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk),

> When using both compat and Modular version, your app will compile, you won't get the app size benefits of the modular code until you fully remove the compat statements and code from your app.